# Empty array while using useState inside alert

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I have an 'exercises' useState. After every change, the useEffect correctly prints the 'exercises,' but after pressing the 'Finish' button, the 'exercises' become empty. What could be the problem? Other use states are ok.
This is my code:

```ts
const [exercises, setExercises] = useState<Exercise[]>([]);
const [title, setTitle] = useState<string>("New Workout");

const handleFinishWorkout = () => {
  Alert.alert(
    "Confirmation",
    "Are you sure you want to finish workout?",
    [
      { text: "No", style: "cancel" },
      {
        text: "Yes",
        onPress: () => {
          const workout: Workout = {
            title: title,
            start_training: new Date().toISOString(),
            end_training: new Date().toISOString(),
            exercises: exercises,
          };
          console.log(exercises);
          navigation.goBack();
        },
      },
    ],
    { cancelable: false },
  );
};

React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log(exercises);
}, [exercises]);
```

this is how function above is called:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerTitle: () => (
        <TextInput
          style={styles.headerTitleInput}
          value={title}
          onChangeText={handleChangeTitle}
        />
      ),
      headerLeft: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleFinishWorkout} style={{ marginLeft: 15 }}>
          <Text style={styles.headerButtonText}>Finish</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    });
  }, [navigation, title]);
```

Comment: What _"Finish button"_?

Comment: Seems like a stale closure problem. Where is `handleFinishWorkout` used? Where is `exercises` being updated that you expect to see updated state in a callback? Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] and details.

Comment: You never call `setExercises`, so `exercises` is not going to change. You create a `Workout` object but do nothing with it.

Comment: I just wanted to say that exercices are updated, I use setExercise several times and with each change, useEffect prints the exercises correctly, but when the handleFinishWorkout function is called, it prints an empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `handleFinishWorkout` function has a stale closure over the `exercises` state created by setting options on the `navigation` object.

You can include the `exercises` state in the `useEffect` hook's dependency array so when that state updates a new closure over it is created.

```js
const handleFinishWorkout = React.useCallback(() => {
  Alert.alert(
    "Confirmation",
    "Are you sure you want to finish workout?",
    [
      { text: "No", style: "cancel" },
      {
        text: "Yes",
        onPress: () => {
          const workout: Workout = {
            title,
            start_training: new Date().toISOString(),
            end_training: new Date().toISOString(),
            exercises,
          };
          console.log(exercises);

          // ... logic that does something with workout

          navigation.goBack();
        },
      },
    ],
    { cancelable: false },
  );
}, [navigation, exercises, title]);

React.useEffect(() => {
  navigation.setOptions({
    headerTitle: () => (
      <TextInput
        style={styles.headerTitleInput}
        value={title}
        onChangeText={handleChangeTitle}
      />
    ),
    headerLeft: () => (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={handleFinishWorkout}
        style={{ marginLeft: 15 }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.headerButtonText}>Finish</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
  });
}, [title, handleChangeTitle, handleFinishWorkout]);
```

An alternative would be to cache the `exercises` state in a React ref where the current value can be referenced in the callback.

Example:

```js
const [exercises, setExercises] = useState<Exercise[]>([]);
const exercisesRef = React.useRef(exercises);

React.useEffect(() => {
  exercisesRef.current = exercises;
}, [exercises]);

const handleFinishWorkout = () => {
  Alert.alert(
    "Confirmation",
    "Are you sure you want to finish workout?",
    [
      { text: "No", style: "cancel" },
      {
        text: "Yes",
        onPress: () => {
          const workout: Workout = {
            title,
            start_training: new Date().toISOString(),
            end_training: new Date().toISOString(),
            exercises: exercisesRef.current,
          };
          console.log(exercisesRef.current);

          // ... logic that does something with workout

          navigation.goBack();
        },
      },
    ],
    { cancelable: false },
  );
};
```